# Validate an input field in HTML having 2 buttons. Validate only for one button click

Tags: angularjs, typescript

This is the HTML file. There is no  used in this. There are two buttons in this HTML. Using angularJS2( typescript )

```
<div class="visitor-entry form-group">
    <!-- [ngClass]="{'validate':vName.errors && (vName.dirty || vName.touched)}"-->
    <div class="ui-input-group">
        <input #vName="ngModel" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name*" name="visitorName" [(ngModel)]="visitorName">
        <span class="input-bar"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Mobile" name="visitorMob" [(ngModel)]="visitorMob">
        <span class="input-bar"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="add-btn-cont">
        <button [disabled]="vName.errors" class="icon-btn" id="addVisitor" title="Add" (click)="addVisitor();"></button>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="block search-add-list active">
    <h6>Person Affected
          <button class="icon-btn pull-right addNewBtn" title="Add New" data-toggle="modal" id="personAffectedBtn" (click)="addNewPerson(personAffectedCode)></button>
        </h6>
</div>
```

Here I want to validate the **visitorName** field mandatory, and add the class `[ngClass]="{'validate':vName.errors && (vName.dirty || vName.touched)}.` . THis should be validated only for first button click.

But if I add **required** to **visitorName** field then it is validating for both the button clicks.

How can I solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the value of required on button click

```
<div class="visitor-entry form-group" >
  <!-- [ngClass]="{'validate':vName.errors && (vName.dirty || vName.touched)}"-->
  <div class="ui-input-group"  >
    <input #vName="ngModel" type="text"  class="form-control" placeholder="Name*" name="visitorName" [(ngModel)]="visitorName" [ngClass]="{'validate':vName.errors && (vName.dirty || vName.touched)}" [required]="{{reqVal}}">
    <span class="input-bar"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="ui-input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Mobile" name="visitorMob" [(ngModel)]="visitorMob">
    <span class="input-bar"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="add-btn-cont">
    <button  [disabled]="vName.errors" class="icon-btn" id="addVisitor" title="Add" (click)="addVisitor();reqVal=false"></button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="block search-add-list active">
    <h6>Person Affected
      <button class="icon-btn pull-right addNewBtn" title="Add New" data-toggle="modal" id="personAffectedBtn" (click)="addNewPerson(personAffectedCode);reqVal=true"></button>
    </h6>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like it works. Tried but its not working  ...[(ngModel)]="visitorName" [ngClass]="{'validate':vName.errors && (vName.dirty || vName.touched)}"  required="{{reqVal}}" ng-required="reqVal">.. syntax any mistake ?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in console? Maybe try setting the value of required inside function call

Comment: No console errors. Tried adding inside method. Tried this also required="{{reqVal}}" & required="reqVal". Angular2 Plunker m not able to add.

Comment: Are you putting this inside a form? Maybe try checking https://angular.io/guide/form-validation

Comment: This component doesn't have any form, but this adding into another parent form like this. @ViewChild(Person) childPersons:Person;

Comment: Ok I am not that familiar with angular 2 form validations. Only thing is to debug the code and see if the boolean values are setting or not. Try printing the values individually in your view and see if it is changing on input and events {{vName.errors}} {{(vName.dirty || vName.touched)}} {{reqVal}}

Comment: Ok will try this. Thank you

Comment: @Rosh Remove ng-required from the answer as it is related to angular 1.x and add corresponding thing for angular 2/4. I think it is [required] for angular 4